# How do I calculate parking rates over several days when rates are specified daily?

Tags: c#, algorithm

I have to calculate total billable amounts for card holders, for card based access to car parks. My rate structure looks like this. Each zone in a car park will have a prioritized list of these prices.

```
public partial class HourlyPrice
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int DayId { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartTime { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndTime { get; set; }
    public int MinHour { get; set; }
    public int MaxHour { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
}
```

`DayId` allows for e.g. 'free on Sundays from 13h00'. `MinNour` and 'MaxHour' allow for 0 to 2 hours is free, where 5 to 6 hours costs R11.00. `StartTime` and `EndTime` allow for 'after 18h00 costs R7.00, flat rate'.

My concern is where no multi-day price is specified. When a car enters under one price structure on one day, and exits under another on another day.  This looks to me like I will have to sequentially visit each hour parked by the vehicle and accumulate the amount due. This seems a very expensive way of doing things.

Any advice on such an endevour would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You could measure the total time spent in each `HourlyPrice` by going from the "current moment" to the border of the corresponding `HourlyPrice`, then making that border moment the "current moment" and recursing (pay attention to overlap).

Comment: "This seems a very expensive way of doing things." How many thousands of cars do you expect to handle per second?

Comment: From looking at your set of requirements, I don't see any way around breaking each parking period down in to hours and calculating the cost per hour using the rule-set. I would love to see other solutions, but I can't think of one...

Comment: @Corak this is a national system, with parkades all over the country, each with multiple zones. Access records will be batched and sent to my calculation server once a day. So, effectively I would like to handle a good several records per second.

Comment: I find it quite difficult to understand well the pricing policy. Here's my understanding. The car holder can park for free as long as his car does not stay parked more than two hours. If the car was parked after the `EndTime` of a day and stays more than the two free hours, its owner will be billed R7.00 if he leaves before the `StartTime` of the following day (and this, whenever he enters and leaves). Am I understanding it well ?

Comment: No @Rerito, there are precedents. Most Start and End times will be 00:00 and 23:59. With just that, 0-2 hours free. If we say after 19:00, the flat rate is R7.00. This will apply until 23:59:59. if he leaves before or at 01h59:50, he gets his first 2 hours free. If he leaves up to 05:59:59, he pays R11.00 for 5-6 hours.

Answer (score 3):

I think this library should solve all your problems:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/168662/Time-Period-Library-for-NET

Comment: That looks very good, and indeed worthy of looking into, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could store the pricing policy of each specific day in an interval tree. The tree should store all the hours of the day. Along with the hour bounds, several information should be held :

- A boolean flat : Is the pricing flat rated ? (e.g. R7.00 for all the period of the interval)
- An integer price : the cost of an hour in the period. If `flat` is set to true, this is the cost of the whole period.

You get parking records in input. I assume they are timestamps for arrival and leaving times for the car. The two first hours are free, so you "increase" the arrival time by two hours. From the resulting timestamps, you could build a sequence of triplets (*day*, *start time*, *end time*). It may be empty (if the car owner parked less than two hours), this case is trivial : costs R0.00

Now, an algorithm that processes the sequence should look like this :

```
cost <- 0
while (NOT is_empty(sequence)) {
    dayTriplet <- pop(sequence)
    down <- dayTriplet.StartTime
    up <- dayTriplet.EndTime
    pricingTree <- getPriceTree(dayTriplet.dayId)
    while (down < up) {
        node <- findNode(pricingTree, down)
        nbHours <- min(up, node.up) - down
        if (node.flat) {
            cost <- cost + node.price
        } else {
            cost <- cost + nbHours*node.price
        }
        down <- down + nbHours
    }
}
```

The algorithm is a bit erroneous but I felt the ideas behind it were worth the shot.
For example, if a car is parked after 18h00 one day until 4h00 the next day, this algorithm would parse (d, 18, 24) and (d+1, 0, 4), and thus the owner should be billed twice the flat rate of the period instead of only once. A carry-like system should do the trick for this issue. I just did not integrated it to leave a relatively clear algorithm.